# How to undo a committed submodule command

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I cloned a repository, and performed some local changes.

Then I did a `git pull origin` to get updated changes from the origin. I then do a `git push` to push to my cloned repository. However, the submodules are not pushed:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    typechange: third_party/aten (new commits)
    modified:   third_party/cub (new commits)
    modified:   third_party/eigen (new commits)
    modified:   third_party/gloo (new commits)
    modified:   third_party/nccl (new commits)
```

I didn't know I could use `git submodule update` to update them. I added them, committed and pushed to my cloned repository.

This is wrong. My cloned repository is lagging behind the origin. Now I have a pull request to the origin and that commit is included.

Just wonder whether there is an easy way to undo that. To force my cloned repository to use the same version as origin.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you Committed only the submodule changes in your last commit then, undo (hard reset) the last commit then, force push to remote (cloned repo)

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1      # undo the last commit
$ git push -f
```

**Alternate way to undo the submodule changes:**

> "It is not the last commit that having this issue" (mentioned in comment)

Checkout the *submodule* folder only to a specific `commit` or `remote branch` where the folder's changes are not committed.

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout <remote>/<branch> -- <submodule-folder>

Or,
$ git log     # copy the commit hash want to get back the submodule folder
$ git checkout <commit-hash> -- <submodule-folder>
```

---

> "To force my cloned repository to use the same version as origin."

Here, I guess `origin` = `upstream` (from where you cloned the repo). So, You can pull the changes from `upstream` then push to cloned repo branch.

```
$ git remote add upstream <upstream repo url> # add a new remote with the original repo url

$ git pull upstream master     # pull the upstream master branch changes into local branch
$ git push                     # update remote branch
```

Now, cloned repo is updated with the original (upstream) repository.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It is not the last commit that having this issue, it is many commits before. I suppose your suggestion would lose all the commits afterwords. Is there a way to only change the submodule version but leaving all other commits intact? Thanks.

Comment: ok then, one way is to revert the commit that having the issue `git revert <commit-hash> ` . Other way is to checkout the submodule folder only to a specific commit `git checkout remote/branch -- <submodule-folder>`.

Comment: Thanks. I used `git chdeckout remote/branch -- <submodule-folder>` and it pulled down the newest changes from the remote.